# How to set a background-image (fixed pattern repeatable) and a background-color changeable depending the content (DIV)

Tags: css, angular

I would like to build a single page application with Angular and I'm struggling to find a way to have a fixed background-image (sort of white pattern repeatable, that could be in the tag BODY).

But depending the content of DIV, I would like to be able to have a different color behind this fixed background-image (for example blue), if you scroll a bit further the color would be red.

Can a css guru solve this issue for me or help me found out how to implement it?

Maybe dealing with z-index, sort of parallax?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet or do you only know what you want? Since you can have both `background-color` and `background-image` there should be no problem in having a fixed `background-image` (with transparancy) and dynamic `background-color`. Since you have chosen angular, I guess you have some knowledge in that framework?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok guys, I have found the solution.

First I set an empty div with my repeat image :
Second I set another empty div with the default background color and the calculated height

```
<body>
  <div class="background"></div>
  <div class="background-color" [ngStyle]="{height:calcHeight}"></div>
  ...

.background{
  background: url(/assets/img/svg/back.svg);
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
}

.background-color{
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #d3d3d3;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: -3;
}
```

Then I can use other colors for next div setting z-index to -2 and another color.

Voila, if someone is interested to know the full code please MP, I will share the website

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of an Angular app where a transparent `background-image` is set statically and the `background-color` is defined inset (in the html code), using "ng-style". The color is a variable set by the user through an input. You probably want something slightly different, but hopefully get the idea!

```js
var myApp = angular.module('app', []);
```

```css
body {
  background-image: url(https://www2.cs.arizona.edu/icon/docs/ipd234/pattern.gif);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="app" ng-style="{'background-color': colorName}">

<input type="text" ng-model="colorName" placeholder="enter a color name e.g. green">
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
body{
 margin:0;
}
.container {
    background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg width='180' height='180' viewBox='0 0 180 180' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%3E%3Cpath d='M82.42 180h-1.415L0 98.995v-2.827L6.167 90 0 83.833V81.004L81.005 0h2.827L90 6.167 96.167 0H98.996L180 81.005v2.827L173.833 90 180 96.167V98.996L98.995 180h-2.827L90 173.833 83.833 180H82.42zm0-1.414L1.413 97.58 8.994 90l-7.58-7.58L82.42 1.413 90 8.994l7.58-7.58 81.006 81.005-7.58 7.58 7.58 7.58-81.005 81.006-7.58-7.58-7.58 7.58zM175.196 0h-25.832c1.033 2.924 2.616 5.59 4.625 7.868C152.145 9.682 151 12.208 151 15c0 5.523 4.477 10 10 10 1.657 0 3 1.343 3 3v4h16V0h-4.803c.51.883.803 1.907.803 3 0 3.314-2.686 6-6 6s-6-2.686-6-6c0-1.093.292-2.117.803-3h10.394-13.685C161.18.938 161 1.948 161 3v4c-4.418 0-8 3.582-8 8s3.582 8 8 8c2.76 0 5 2.24 5 5v2h4v-4h2v4h4v-4h2v4h2V0h-4.803zm-15.783 0c-.27.954-.414 1.96-.414 3v2.2c-1.25.254-2.414.74-3.447 1.412-1.716-1.93-3.098-4.164-4.054-6.612h7.914zM180 17h-3l2.143-10H180v10zm-30.635 163c-.884-2.502-1.365-5.195-1.365-8 0-13.255 10.748-24 23.99-24H180v32h-30.635zm12.147 0c.5-1.416 1.345-2.67 2.434-3.66l-1.345-1.48c-1.498 1.364-2.62 3.136-3.186 5.14H151.5c-.97-2.48-1.5-5.177-1.5-8 0-12.15 9.84-22 22-22h8v30h-18.488zm13.685 0c-1.037-1.793-2.976-3-5.197-3-2.22 0-4.16 1.207-5.197 3h10.394zM0 148h8.01C21.26 148 32 158.742 32 172c0 2.805-.48 5.498-1.366 8H0v-32zm0 2h8c12.15 0 22 9.847 22 22 0 2.822-.53 5.52-1.5 8h-7.914c-.567-2.004-1.688-3.776-3.187-5.14l-1.346 1.48c1.09.99 1.933 2.244 2.434 3.66H0v-30zm15.197 30c-1.037-1.793-2.976-3-5.197-3-2.22 0-4.16 1.207-5.197 3h10.394zM0 32h16v-4c0-1.657 1.343-3 3-3 5.523 0 10-4.477 10-10 0-2.794-1.145-5.32-2.992-7.134C28.018 5.586 29.6 2.924 30.634 0H0v32zm0-2h2v-4h2v4h4v-4h2v4h4v-2c0-2.76 2.24-5 5-5 4.418 0 8-3.582 8-8s-3.582-8-8-8V3c0-1.052-.18-2.062-.512-3H0v30zM28.5 0c-.954 2.448-2.335 4.683-4.05 6.613-1.035-.672-2.2-1.16-3.45-1.413V3c0-1.04-.144-2.046-.414-3H28.5zM0 17h3L.857 7H0v10zM15.197 0c.51.883.803 1.907.803 3 0 3.314-2.686 6-6 6S4 6.314 4 3c0-1.093.292-2.117.803-3h10.394zM109 115c-1.657 0-3 1.343-3 3v4H74v-4c0-1.657-1.343-3-3-3-5.523 0-10-4.477-10-10 0-2.793 1.145-5.318 2.99-7.132C60.262 93.638 58 88.084 58 82c0-13.255 10.748-24 23.99-24h16.02C111.26 58 122 68.742 122 82c0 6.082-2.263 11.636-5.992 15.866C117.855 99.68 119 102.206 119 105c0 5.523-4.477 10-10 10zm0-2c-2.76 0-5 2.24-5 5v2h-4v-4h-2v4h-4v-4h-2v4h-4v-4h-2v4h-4v-4h-2v4h-4v-2c0-2.76-2.24-5-5-5-4.418 0-8-3.582-8-8s3.582-8 8-8v-4c0-2.64 1.136-5.013 2.946-6.66L72.6 84.86C70.39 86.874 69 89.775 69 93v2.2c-1.25.254-2.414.74-3.447 1.412C62.098 92.727 60 87.61 60 82c0-12.15 9.84-22 22-22h16c12.15 0 22 9.847 22 22 0 5.61-2.097 10.728-5.55 14.613-1.035-.672-2.2-1.16-3.45-1.413V93c0-3.226-1.39-6.127-3.6-8.14l-1.346 1.48C107.864 87.987 109 90.36 109 93v4c4.418 0 8 3.582 8 8s-3.582 8-8 8zM90.857 97L93 107h-6l2.143-10h1.714zM80 99c3.314 0 6-2.686 6-6s-2.686-6-6-6-6 2.686-6 6 2.686 6 6 6zm20 0c3.314 0 6-2.686 6-6s-2.686-6-6-6-6 2.686-6 6 2.686 6 6 6z' fill='%239C92AC' fill-opacity='0.4' fill-rule='evenodd'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
    position: fixed;
    width:100%
    height:100%
 
}
.red{
 background-color:red;
}
.black{
 background-color:black;
 color:white;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
</div>
<div class="red">
<h1>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</h1>
</div>

<div><h1>It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).
</h1>
</div>

<div class="black">
<h1>Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32.
</h1>
</div>
```

Hi Thank you for your answer but it is not the intended use of my website.

I would like to have the possibility to have a DIV with a background-color blue and another one red.

I have found a way to do it but only if the background-image is fixed, when i try with absolute the background-image has an end :(

Another problem is that the image is in front...

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to add a transparent color overlay over a background image. You can achieve this using psuedo elements. Try using the after selector to add an overlay on top of your container:

```
.container {
    background-image: url(...);
}

.container:after {
    z-index: 1;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: rgba(255,0,0,.8);  // set alpha to transparency 
}
```

Comment: please have a look to my answer with the code snippet. thanks